# Building packages from launchpad respository

Tags: package-management

I'd like to build a [package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt) directly from the upstream (launchpad) repository. I've read the various packaging guides and I'm still not sure what the best practice is.

Essentially, how do I build a package from launchpad, handling dependencies and chrooted build environments just like the [build bots](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/172803944/buildlog_ubuntu-trusty-amd64.libvirt_1.2.2-0ubuntu13_UPLOADING.txt.gz) do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software used to build Ubuntu source packages in a chroot is called [sbuild](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sbuild) [image: Install sbuild]. Some introduction to setting up and using sbuild is given in the [SimpleSbuild](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SimpleSbuild) wiki article.

There are many ways to download a source package and to set up an sbuild chroot, but the [ubuntu-dev-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-dev-tools) [image: Install ubuntu-dev-tools] package includes a couple of very useful scripts for accomplishing exactly what you want.

Assuming you are running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, you can set up a chroot and build the `bash` package for example, with

```
sudo apt-get install sbuild ubuntu-dev-tools
mk-sbuild trusty
pull-lp-source -d bash trusty
sbuild -A -d trusty bash_4.3-7ubuntu1.5.dsc
```

where the filename of the source package given to the `sbuild` command will of course change with updates and new releases.

The `mk-sbuild` command need only be run one time, the minimal chroot is cached on your system and can be reused for building any number of source packages.